# Etymology of "nasal specs" as a synonym for "nasal cannula"?

Tags: etymology, synonyms, medical

For context, this is in the UK—I was told by someone they had been given "nasal specs"—which was the term they had been told when they got them, and then I asked someone I know who is a retired medical professional, and they said that was the term they used (to the extent "nasal cannula" was an unusual term for them, while they understood it, not something they would use).

So this appears to be a common term used in the UK, as far as I can tell, but I couldn't find anyone who knows or any source for where it comes from. Searches online treat it as a synonym, and I can find usages of it, but I can't find anything describing the origin or what "specs" is in this context.

My assumption is that it is an analogy to glasses, i.e: "nasal spectacles" because of the way you wear them. It still feels odd to me but it's the only idea I have that makes any sense. I'm interested if anyone can prove or disprove this theory?

Here is what the device looks like:

[image: A woman wearing a tube running over her ears, across her face, with two prongs to deliver a gas directly into her nose.]

Comment: Can you explain what this things is and add a picture? It is unclear what exactly you're talking about.

Comment: @Mitch There's a photo at the link for my first example.

Comment: @DjinTonic That's what -you- think it is, not what the OP thinks it is.

Comment: @Mitch if you mean I'm presuming, I agree. Or do you mean you think he definitely means something else?

Comment: @DjinTonic You're probably right, but you're still presuming. I hadn't heard of either before googling.

Comment: @Mitch I hadn't either. In fact, I started out  my search thinking the term  came from one similar function of the instrument, a nasal speculum. Also, we posted at about the same time, and I wasn't sure you saw the photo I included.

Comment: @Mitch I can confirm I was talking about the thing pictured in the first link in [DjinTonic's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/580069/74413) (a tube running over someone's ears, across their face, with two prongs to deliver a gas directly into their nose).

Comment: @Latty OK Great... You should put that info in your question.

Comment: @Mitch I did exactly that when I posted that comment.

Comment: Holy cannoli, Batman, a synesthetic misnomer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Nasal cannulas** are medical devices used when people are unable to get sufficient oxygen to keep their body functioning optimally,
> whether that's due to a condition like chronic obstructive pulmonary
> disease (COPD), another respiratory disorder, or an environmental
> change. [verywellhealth.com](https://www.verywellhealth.com/nasal-cannulas-914867) [with **photo**]

> Dual prong nasal cannulae or '**nasal specs**' actually perform like a
> variable performance mask. [Peter Driscoll et al.; *Safe Transfer and Retrieval*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Safe_Transfer_and_Retrieval_STaR_of_Pati/jbBizccF-10C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=breathing%20with%20%22nasal%20specs%22&pg=PA62&printsec=frontcover)

> Nasal cannulae should be positioned with one cannula in each nostril...
> **The oxygen tubing should be placed over and around the patient's ears,
> and secured under the chin (like wearing a pair of glasses). Hence
> they are colloquially known as nasal specs**. [T. Martin;
> *Aeromedical Transportation*](https://books.google.com/books?id=XOjeDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT172&lpg=PT172&dq=%22Hence+they+are+colloquially+known+as+nasal+specs.%22&source=bl&ots=znh7mPPUuS&sig=ACfU3U1tPfTWJe6GpQom1teyXkjDZYSDXg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjs08O6n_uCAxWU7gIHHfTtAIgQ6AF6BAgFEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Hence%20they%20are%20colloquially%20known%20as%20nasal%20specs.%22&f=false)

I was wondering whether there is also a connection to the instrument, a [**nasal speculum**](https://www.google.com/search?q=nasal%20speculum&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS911US911&oq=nasal%20speculum&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i67j0i512j0i67j0i512l6.7872j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), but the only connection I've found so far is this example of "specs" short for (vaginal) specula:

> Single-use speculum eliminates the time and expense of reprocessing
> metal **specs** [AxiomMedicals](https://axiommedicals.com/products/welch-allyn-vaginal-speculum-kleenspec-r-590-series-premium-pederson-nonsterile-office-grade-acrylic-large-double-blade-duckbill-disposable-built-in-light-source-m-994808-1757-box-of-14?variant=40005373165757)

**speculum** (plural *specula* also *speculums*)

> An instrument inserted into a body passage especially to facilitate
> visual inspection or medication [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/speculum)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I guess I managed to infer my way back to the right answer, but I do wonder what made it the preferred term (at least in my small survey of two points across the country) here in the UK. I suspect that's unknowable at this point though.

Comment: A quick google search for your speculative idea of 'nasal speculum' shows something to look up the nostrils, not to provide oxygen like nasal cannulae.

Comment: It's *also* used to help administer medicine (as I found out at several recent ENT visits and the definition states) and one informal plural appears to be "specs". And the cannulae may also help keep the nostrils open.

Answer (score 1):

After some brief internet searching I would hazard to guess the term may have originated from the 'Tudor-Edwards Spectacle Frame Catheter Carrier' which appears to have been previously used as a mechanism to deliver oxygen therapy nasally. However, I am not certain if this is definitely the origins or the correct reasoning for the term but it is definitely a possible explanation.

Reference:
Leigh JM. The evolution of oxygen therapy apparatus. *Anaesthesia*. 1974:29; 462-485.

Comment: From [1983](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC459511/pdf/thorax00207-0001.pdf): "Recently nasal catheters, a simplification of earlier Tudor Edwards **nasal spectacles**, have been found to be just as effective as HAFOE masks."